# clang warning argument unused during compilation for -fsanitize-address-outline-instrumentation

Tags: clang, llvm, riscv

I am trying to test out whether the flag `-fsanitize-address-outline-instrumentation` works for the LLVM Clang compiler.

```
Ubuntu clang version 15.0.7
```

I have created an exemplary program:

main.c

```
#include "stdio.h"

static inline void printFunc(void)
{
    printf("Test string \r\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    printFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to verify whether the `printFunc` would be inlined or not, depeneding on whether the `-fsanitize-address-outline-instrumentation` compilation flag is added. When I try to compile the file, the compiler returns during compilation:

```
lukasz@lp:/tmp/test$ clang main.c -o main -fsanitize-address-outline-instrumentation
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fsanitize-address-outline-instrumentation' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

I cannot figure out why is the parameter ignored.

Comment: There is no `-fsanitize-address-outline-instrumentation` in clang

Comment: Do you know the Clang equivalent to disallow functions to be inlined?

Comment: Compiling the code with `-fno-inline-functions` produces the same output binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way for disabling inlining is to use the `-fno-inline-functions`. But for the inlining to even work in the first place, optimization has to be used, i.e. `-O2` or `-Oz`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was not working is because I did not add the `-fsanitize=address` as well. So when compiled with `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize-address-outline-instrumentation` it works- the generated binary has different size.

However, the produced binary is actually bigger than before. So I am not sure this solves the issue.